# Error message of "Found more than one Organisation with same Name"

Tags: api, error, user-account

Getting the following error whenever a user tries to create a new account on the system: CRM_Core_Exception: Found more than one Organisation with same Name. in civicrm_api3() (line 135 of /storage/drupal/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php).

This is the only error message I get, nothing in the PHP or NGINX logs. If somebody could point me in the right direction that would be very helpful.

Enviroment info:

- CiviCRM v5.57.1
- Drupal 7.94
- NGINX on Debian

Comment: Welcome to SE!  Do you have any custom extensions or use CiviRules?  Sounds like some code firing when an account is created but isn't handling this condition well.

Comment: Does this happen for any names or just a specific one? And do you mean create a new Drupal user account.